# Objective-C, Doxygen and how to show AppKit classes in documentation

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, doxygen, doxywizard

I am looking to include AppKit classes in inheritance information. For example, if I have SuperWindowController and it inherits from NSWindowController, then I would like that mentioned in the generated HTML files. In my case, I am actually more interested in the XML files, so what I'd like to see there is something like this:

> <compounddef id="interface_super_window_controller" kind="class" prot="public">
>
> <compoundname>CBWindowController</compoundname>
>
> <basecompoundref refid="interface" prot="public">NSWindowController<
>   /basecompoundref>
>
> </compounddef>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need custom tag files that link to Apple's website. I created a set of them that you [download](http://cocoa.agilemonks.com/2011/01/12/linking-doxygen-generated-docs-to-apples-docs/) from my blog.